# Responsive bootstrap menu following the width

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I'm using bootstrap for my responsive menu. It is working perfect for the desktop and mobile.

By the way I want the menu look like this for certain width. (iPad, iPad Pro)

- Desktop

```
| LOGO   A   B   C   D |
```

- **iPad & iPad Pro**

```
| LOGO   A   B   ≡ |
```

- Mobile

```
| LOGO     ≡ |
```

Can I achieve this using bootstrap or any other javascript libraries?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it using bootstrap!

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara, thanks for your reply, will you post some more details here? I can make this menu using javascript btw I want to know the best option for this.